# Google Tango: how to activate ART runtime

Tags: google-project-tango

When I open tango explorer, I get this error:
Runtime mismatch, go to system setting and use ART as runtime.

The thing when I looked in the net, it told me to go to settings->developers->runtime, but there is no ran called developers or runtime in the settings. Could someone assist please?!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is that Tango won't work at all with Dalvik - if any of the demos work, you're good to go  :-)

Answer (score 0):

if Tango Device set runtime with Dalvik, it still works for some apps, but it can't give you best performance.

For better performance, Please use ART runtime.
TangoExplorer had UX Framework, it will remind you that you are running on Dalvik instead of ART.

For Setting runtime, 
First enable Developer options by click Build Number 7 times
then goto Settings->Developer options -> Select runtime -> ART

The device will reset itself

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:
Go to settings, about this device, the very last option is Bundle Identifier, tap on it around 6 times, it will add the developers tab in settings.
(Google... Why?!)

And yes, demos work on Dalvik and the performance is far more better than ART but accompained with a warning/error message asking you to switch between them.